# Reverse command line arguments in shell script

Tags: linux

What is the best way to reverse the command line arguments passed to a shell script in Linux?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you wanna do, and it seems to me that this question is best suited for superuser.com

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21388

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about "best", but this should work:

```
for i; do args="$i $args"; done
set -- $args
```

Note that this does not affect `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for reversing the arguments, last argument being processed first then the following might help

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=$#
for x in "$@";do
  echo $i
  i=`expr $i - 1` 
done
```

Results :

```sh
$> bash test.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9
8
7
6
5
4 
3 
2
1
```